# Static methods and parameters

Tags: typescript, class, static

I wanted to declare a static function on a class, but it needs a (classic) method from another class. So I also put this class as a static parameter, initialised in the constructor.

However, when we call a static class, we don't use the constructor, so this second class isn't initialised either. So I wonder how it is working (because it seems to work for me, but I cannot see how).

If someone could either explain this to me or tell me it isn't supposed to work.

Here is the interesting part of my class:

```js
export class DestinationController {
    private static readonly CACHE_KEY = "destination::";

    private static cacheController: CacheController;

    constructor(
        cacheController: CacheController,
        private readonly categoryController: CategoryController,
        ...
    ) {
        DestinationController.cacheController = cacheController
    }

    static async clearCache(destinationSlug: string): Promise<void> {
        await this.cacheController.del(this.CACHE_KEY + destinationSlug); // As the method itself is static I figured that this.etc is the same as DestinationController.etc
    }

    ...
}
```

With that I can call from any other controller `DestinationController.clearCache("someDestination")`.

And my `CacheController` starts like this

```js
export class CacheController {
    private client: WrappedNodeRedisClient;

    private defaultTtlSeconds: number;

    /**
     * @param host Redis host
     * @param defaultTtlSeconds Default time to live which is applied when storing keys
     */
    constructor(host: string, defaultTtlSeconds: number) {
        this.client = createNodeRedisClient({ host });
        this.defaultTtlSeconds = defaultTtlSeconds;
    }

    ...
}
```

In this case, the parameters of the CacheController are constants, so I can just initialise it at the same time as I declare it, but what if the parameters are other controllers that also have to be initialised?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem: Something we can copy and paste and run to see that it "works". (The [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) is good for making sure your example is entirely self-contained; be sure to put the code in the question as well, not just a link to the playground.) Right now, your question has no calls to `DestinationController`'s constructor, so any call to `DestinationController.clearCache` **will** fail with an error attempting to access `del` on `undefined`. So we need more info in order to help you.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, though, initializing a `static` property from a constructor parameter is an anti-pattern. Each call to the constructor will replace the static field, leading to unexpected results and cross-talk between disparate parts of the code that use `DestinationController`.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, that's what I thought. It seemed stranged to me, even if TS let me do it and it worked. It it surely worked because I indeed initialized it one (and only one) time. Thanks for your clear answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is an anti-pattern. For `this.cacheController.del` in your static method to work, you would have needed to first initialise `CacheController` and use that to initialise `DestinationController`.

I don't really see a reason to making `cacheController` in `DestinationController` static from your code snippets.

Can it be refactored to this?

```
export class DestinationController {
  private static readonly CACHE_KEY = "destination::";

  private cacheController: CacheController;

  constructor(
      cacheController: CacheController,
      private readonly categoryController: any,
  ) {
      this.cacheController = cacheController
  }

  async clearCache(destinationSlug: string): Promise<void> {
      await this.cacheController.del(DestinationController.CACHE_KEY);
  }
}
```

Comment: For me, from what I understood from the courses I had and especially what we did in Java, this function looks more like a static function, general for the class itself, not an instance of it. But thanks for the explanation at the start, that's what I was looking for!